# Python is failing to recognize the column with index of variables

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I read an excel file using pandas which contains python data frame. The data frame was initially turned into an excel file using ExcelWriter. The data frame looks like this in excel:

```
df:

Index    Variables
0        Index(['Growth', 'Pure growth', 'Value'], dtype='object')
1        Index(['Growth', 'Pure growth', 'Quality'], dtype='object')
.
.
.
```

However, after reading the file, python is failing to recognise that variables column in an index not string.

```
type(df['Variables'][0])
>>str
```

How can I turn the column back into an index format?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you show the code you're using currently?

Comment: Could you post code which has some sample data? This will help reproduce the problem, which there's no way to do currently

Answer (score 0):

Excel does not store special python objects like a pandas Index. This is indeed a string. The best thing is to store the Index at a column or at a row at the 1st step and not in a signle cell. At the current configuration, you have to deal with this str. You can store the Index values (you want a fromat like: 'Growth', 'Pure growth', 'Value') and when you read it back to python, segment each string to the individual parts - play with the argumnet of str.split(' ,'), you can also use apply_along_axis() to apply the split to the whole column. Lastly, convert the list that you got from split into an index object.